# how to make Linq Expression to receive parameter onto a linq query in a generic repository

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

When I am trying to create a join with a IEnumerable Collection with a DbSet it throws the following exception,so  i am thinking i could include a property then filter by this property I need and select it...

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
.Join(
inner: __p_0,
outerKeySelector: y => y.IdToken,
innerKeySelector: z => z.IdToken,
resultSelector: (tokens, userTokens) => tokens)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

```
   

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> Join<Tkey, TEntity, VKey, TResult>(IEnumerable<TEntity> collection, Expression<Func<T, Tkey>> outerSelector, Expression<Func<TEntity, Tkey>> innerSelector, Expression<Func<T, TEntity, TResult>> resultSelector)
            where TEntity : class, new()
             where TResult:class,new()
        {
           
                return await Db.Set<T>().Join(collection, outerSelector, innerSelector, resultSelector).ToListAsync();
            
        }
```

now the query I want to use is like this

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> Join<Tkey,TIncludeProperty, TEntity, TResult>(IEnumerable<T> collection,Expression<Func<T,TIncludeProperty>> includeClause, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>, bool> whereFilter, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> resultSelector)
      where TEntity : class, new()
       where TResult :class,new()
        where TIncludeProperty: class,new()
    {
        try
        {
           
            return await Db.Set<T>().Include(includeClause).Where(x=>whereFilter(x,collection)).Select(resultSelector).ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();
        }
    }
```

how can i pass to whereFilter the collection on the method's signature?

Answer (score 2):

the solution was fixing the query and using a where filter also overloading to add another where filter

```cs
 public async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> Join<TIncludeProperty, TEntity, TResult>(IEnumerable<T> collection,Expression<Func<T,TIncludeProperty>> includeClause, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> resultSelector)
      where TEntity : class, new()
       where TResult : class, new()
        where TIncludeProperty: class,new()
    {
        try
        {
            
            return await Db.Set<T>().Include(includeClause).Where(y=> collection.Contains(y)).Select(resultSelector).ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();
        }
    } 

   public async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> Join<TIncludeProperty, TEntity, TResult>(IEnumerable<T> collection, Expression<Func<T, TIncludeProperty>> includeClause, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> resultSelector, Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereFilter)
      where TEntity : class, new()
       where TResult : class, new()
        where TIncludeProperty : class, new()
    {
        try
        {
            
            return await Db.Set<T>().Include(includeClause).Where(x=> collection.Contains(x)).Where(whereFilter).Select(resultSelector).ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

hi you can use this logic
,,,

```
 public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>>  Where=null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;
            if(Where != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(Where);
            }
            return query.ToList();
        }
```

,,,
i hope this help you